# Error on ifort environment variables set

Tags: environment-variables, intel, intel-fortran

I have installed intel Composer XE, because I needed the intel compilers.

Problem is, when I finish the installation I got this message:

> To get started using Intel(R) Composer XE 2011 Update 9 located in
>   /home/gsrodrigues/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293:
>
> - Set the environment variables for a terminal window using one of the following   (replace "intel64" with "ia32" if you are using a 32-bit
>     platform).
>
>   For csh/tcsh:
>
>   ```
>   $ source install-dir/bin/compilervars.csh intel64
>   ```
>
>   For bash:
>
>   To invoke the installed compilers:
>         $ source install-dir/bin/compilerv
>     ars.sh intel64
>
>   ```
>   For C++: icpc
>
>   For C: icc
>
>   For Fortran: ifort
>   ```
>
>   To get help, append the -help option or precede with the man command.
> - To view a table of getting started documents:
>     install-dir/Documentation/en_US/documentation_f.htm.

But Every time I try to use the 'intel64' command I got this message:

> -bash: /home/gsrodrigues/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.9.293/bin/intel64/idbvars.sh: No such file or directory

And when I use the 'ia32' command no problem appears, but still I can't create a simple fortran executable.

Comment: `idbvars.sh` is the evironment settings for the intel source debugger. You can either comment out the line which loads it, or install the debugger (you might want to do that if you plan on serious development anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you've only installed the 32-bit version of Intel Composer?